# Spring form submit validation for foreign key

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

My project is a spring mvc project.In my project i have a domain Technology which has foreign key reference.When i validating on form submit it threw error....For view part(jsp),i using form:select for viewing department in technology.
How can i validate a foreign reference?????
i tried below code

**domain**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "technology")
public class Technology {
private int id;
@NotEmpty
private String name;
@NotEmpty
private Department department;
private Date createdDate;
private boolean isDelete;
}
```

**message.properties**

```
NotEmpty.technology.department=Required!
```

**Technology.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" action="add-technology"
            commandName="technology" id="technologyForm">

            <label>Technology Name</label>
            <form:input path="name" /><form:errors path="name" class="error"></form:errors>
            <br />
            <label>Department</label>
            <form:select path="department.id">

                <form:option value="0" label="Select" />

                <form:options items="${departments}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />

            </form:select><form:errors path="department" class="error"></form:errors>
            <%--    <form:select path="department.id" items="${departments}" /> --%>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

        </form:form>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-technology")
public String addTechnology(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "technology")@Valid Technology technology,
        BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "/secure/admin/technology";
    }
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
    technology.setCreatedDate(sqlDate);

    technologyService.saveTechnology(technology);
    return "redirect:/technologies";
}
```

**ERROR**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: com.company.product.domain.Department
```

How can i resolve this problem???

Comment: @NotEmpty Asserts that the annotated string, collection, map or array is not null or empty.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html  you can use '@Valid' on Department.

Comment: you mean department domain or technology domain???

Comment: @Valid private Department department;  and you can use jsr 303 validation on attribute of Department domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to implement validator for Technology object

```
class TechnologyValidator extends Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> cls) {
        return Technology .class.equals(cls);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        super.validate(target, errors);
        Technology tecObj= (Technology ) target;
        //here i am assuming Technology name is REQUIRED and   
        //NotEmpty.technology.name is in message.properties
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors,"name",
                                           "NotEmpty.technology.name");


      Department dept = tecObj.getDepartment();
      //as from from your are binding department ID
      if (dept==null || dept.getId()==null || dept.getId()==0L ) {
         errors.rejectValue("department.id", "NotEmpty.technology.department");
      }
  }
}
```

And **create bean** of this class in Spring-context

```
@Autowired
TechnologyValidator techValid;
```

And call this validator in your controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-technology")
public String addTechnology(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "technology") Technology technology,
        BindingResult result) {

    //call validator
    techValid.validate(technology, result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "/secure/admin/technology";
    }
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
    technology.setCreatedDate(sqlDate);

    technologyService.saveTechnology(technology);
    return "redirect:/technologies";
}
```

Comment: do i need to add @NotEmpty annotation on Technology domain??

Comment: there is a error on     "super.validate(target, errors);"

Comment: do i need to add @NotEmpty annotation for department on Technology domain??

Comment: There is no error it is not showing information (Required)for department

Comment: check that I just updated Validator part code to validate department

Comment: Above code is working but not showing validation message

Comment: Please change form error on your JSP to <form:errors path="department.id" class="error"></form:errors>